# Is there a way I can provide data to stakeholders from DB, about latest data points without manual export

Tags: database, mongodb, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, cyberduck

I want to export data from mongodb automatically, and upload to S3 Bucket, and create a pre-signed url to then send to stakeholders.

In my production project, the clients wants weekly updates on DB. I am ssh tunnelling into a server, then connecting to Mongodb via connection string, then exporting data from MongoDB manually with some specific fields to JSON, then converting to CSV.

I then open up Cyberduck and connect to S3 Bucket, I upload to the s3 bucket and right click on the file and copy a presigned version which means the link will expire and then provide the link to the client.

Is there a way I can make this faster and/or automated completely?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question in line with [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Especially making the question more focused - "exporting data" are you exporting all data? Changesets?

Comment: Yes I am exporting all the data, and they want specific things with the data file like having a pre-signed URL and uploading to S3. Should I just write a script? Should i use powershell? I've never written anything like this before.

I've updated the question to be clearer

Comment: Ah, I understand - The only aspect of this which is related to AWS is the S3 bit which you can use the AWS CLI for (powershell) or the SDK for uploading and creating the link. But considering everything else in this is manual, automating just that bit won't really be beneficial. Try automating the SSHing into the machine, use the Mongo CLI to generate the backup, then perhaps some form of command line CSV converter so then all you need to do is login, transfer and then upload. Or alternatively, give your server S3 access and allow it to just upload to S3 itself

Comment: Ok thanks, I cant pick your response as the answer unfortunately, its not letting me since its a response.

Comment: I'll add in an answer which is a bit more formulated in a bit :)